# NGinx reverse proxy force move user to different server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We are using NGinx in front of Apache to load balance web traffic - is it possible to move a specific user (IP address I assume) to specific a Apache server?

We are doing some work and some of our IP's connect to server 1, some connect to server 2 and so on. Changes are sent via FTP to server 1 and then replicated across the other nodes.

We would like all our IP addresses/users to point to server 1 so we don't have to wait for changes to be replicated across the hosts to check if something has worked if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, however you might end duplicating a lot of config (`include` is you friend in that case) and if you have many locations you might also run into trouble.

```
upstream AllServers {
                server server1.example.com;
                server server2.example.com;
                ......
                }

Server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;

    error_page 403 = @internal;

    location / {
                deny youip;
                allow all;
                proxy_pass http://AllServers;
                <rest of config>
                }

    location @internal{
                proxy_pass http://server1.example.com
                <rest of config>
                }
        }
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, post a copy of your config so I can see if something conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using an extra URL parameter in requests that one wants to direct to a particular server. In my solution, I can connect to `https://example.com?direct=1` to make the request go to the server on the same node as nginx is running, or whichever node is specified under the `if` statement.

This is for PHP-FPM, but the concept is similar for reverse proxy with `proxy_pass`. Just replace `fastcgi_pass` with `proxy_pass`. The solution looks like this:

```
server {
    ... other config ...
    location <appserver> {
        if ($arg_direct = 1) {
            set $upstream unix:/srw/www/example.com/php.sock; # Local upstream server
        }
        if ($arg_direct = 2) {
            set $upstream 10.10.10.1:9000; # Other node IP & Port
        }
        if ($arg_direct !~ "[12]") {
            set $upstream example.com; # Default load balanced group
        }
        fastcgi_pass $upstream;
    }
}

upstream example.com {
    ip_hash;
    server unix:/srw/www/example.com/php.sock
    server 10.10.10.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: Regarding replication, I recommend that you take a look at `lsyncd` daemon, with that replication doesn't take more than a couple of seconds, depending on the number of changes though.